# JavaScript Object planned output does't match

Tags: javascript

End of the code is:

```
console.log ("Name: " + pete.fullname() + "\tAge:" + pete.age);
console.log ("Name: " + cara.fullname() + "\tAge:" + cara.age);
console.log (cara.firstname + "is" + (cara.age - pete.age) + " year older than " + pete.firstname);
```

I wrote it:

```
pete = {
firstname: "Pete",
lastname: "Programmer",
age: 20
};
var cara = {
firstname: "Cara",
lastname: "Coder",
age: 30,
};
pete.fullname = function (){
console.log (pete.firstname + pete.lastname)
};
cara.fullname = function () {
console.log (cara.firstname + 
cara.lastname)
};

console.log ("Name: " + pete.fullname() + "\tAge:" + pete.age);
console.log ("Name: " + cara.fullname() + "\tAge:" + cara.age);
console.log (cara.firstname + "is" + (cara.age - pete.age) + " year older than " + pete.firstname);
```

Planned output:

```
Name: Pete Programmer   Age:20 Name: 
Cara Coder  Age:32
Cara is 12 years older than Pete
```

Don't understand why I have this output:

```
PeteProgrammer
Name: undefined Age:20
CaraCoder
Name: undefined Age:30
Cara is 10 years older than Pete
```

Comment: Your `fullname` function doesn't have a `return` statement so it returns `undefined`

Comment: As for `PeteProgrammer Name: undefined`, that _order_ is the result of your nesting of `console.log` calls into each other. So the output of the _inner_ `log()` will appear in the console first, and then that of the second. Nested function calls are always evaluated starting with the innermost one, and then working its way "outwards".

Comment: To use a function in a string concatenation you need to return some value from the function here e.g. `return petefirstname + pete.lastname` instead of the console.log

Comment: I have output: PeteProgrammer but need Pete Programmer

Answer (score 0):

In `pete.fullname()` and `cara.fullname()` functions you're doing `console.log()` instead of `return`. The code:

```js
pete = {
firstname: "Pete",
lastname: "Programmer",
age: 20
};
var cara = {
firstname: "Cara",
lastname: "Coder",
age: 30,
};
pete.fullname = function (){
return pete.firstname + pete.lastname
}
cara.fullname = function () {
return cara.firstname + 
cara.lastname
};

console.log ("Name: " + pete.fullname() + "\tAge:" + pete.age);
console.log ("Name: " + cara.fullname() + "\tAge:" + cara.age);
console.log (cara.firstname + " is " + (cara.age - pete.age) + " year older than " + pete.firstname);
```